# Algorithm to check for connected neighbors in a two-dimensional array

Tags: c#, algorithm

For a game (WPF) I need to create a map editor. A map is defined by a matrix of 4x3 map fields. When the user edits the map, he can enable and disable each of the fields, with this he defines how the map look like. Now a map is only valid, if each of the the fields are connected to another field. I.e. this map is valid (blue is active, gray inactive):

[image]

I have a two-dimensional array with the map fields. Each of the fields has a `boolean` value which defines if it's active or not. To check if map is valid I've written the following method:

```
private bool IsMapPlayable()
{
    int numberOfActiveFields = 0;
    for (var row = 0; row < this.GameFields.Length; row++)
    {
        for (var col = 0; col < this.GameFields[row].Length; col++)
        {
            if (!this.GameFields[row][col].IsActive) continue;
            numberOfActiveFields++;

            if (!(row > 0 && this.GameFields[row - 1][col].IsActive)
                && !(row + 1 < this.GameFields.Length && this.GameFields[row + 1][col].IsActive)
                && !(col > 0 && this.GameFields[row][col - 1].IsActive)
                && !(col + 1 < this.GameFields[row].Length && this.GameFields[row][col + 1].IsActive)
                && numberOfActiveFields > 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return numberOfActiveFields > 0;
}
```

This method only checks if each field has a direct active neighbor field (and has either exactly 1 active field or more than 1 active fields). Unfortunately with this method, the following maps are also valid:

[image]

[image]

But these maps should not be valid. What would be most efficient algorithm to check if a map is valid or not?

Comment: Does every map always start with the top left field as active?

Comment: No, you could define the map as you want. So it could also only have fields [2][2] and [2][3] active.

Comment: Can a field be connected to more than two other fields. For example could [2][2] be connected to [1][2], [2][1], and [2][3]?

Comment: @JamesWarne yes it can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pair of methods:

Execute [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) from any active cell, and after ending check that all active cells are marked

Use [union-find data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) (you need not any optimizations for such small grids), insert active cells with active neighbours,  and check that there is only one connected component